# java import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, weblogic

I've imported my java workspace containing 5 projects on this new installation: I switch from a pc 32 bits to 64 bits (not relevant IMO).

I have this error on one project :

```
The type org.apache.log4j.Level cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

And this one on another one :

```
The type org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

And finally this one, a bit different :

```
The import javax.ejb cannot be resolved
```

The last one refers to a jar contained in the weblogic system library, included in the classpath and well important. As you can see here :

[image]

These projects have also a shared lib called PCDD_W

[image: java build path]

and this shared lib contains log4j.jar, in which is the Level.class and the spring-core.jar containing NestedRuntimeExceptionClass with the right path.

[image]

We can see here that the shared lib is well included and contains the Level class (the same in the other project) :
[image]

When I click on the Level class in Eclipse, in the code, the correct Level.class is opened. So Eclipse can find it but it may not be correctly put in my build path.

It's an ant project (not a maven one).

I use eclipse photon and my java project run on WebLogic 10.3.6, JDK 1.6

Comment: hi, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363240/1004631

Comment: @robot_alien : Thanks for your answer but in this project Log4j version is 1.2 and I can't do the upgrade to Log4j 2. This version works fine on my old PC, here it seems that I miss a step in my installation / local configuration.